# Angular set null to User object on logout

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a simple user authentication app in Angular following this [tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/29/angular-7-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial). I am facing an error when I am trying to set null to the User object after the user has logged out.

Error:

```
ERROR in src/app/_services/authentication.service.ts(40,38): error TS2345: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
```

Relevant code (authentication.service.ts):

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

import {User} from '@/_models';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthenticationService{
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public currentUser: Observable<User>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}'));
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): User{
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

    login(username: string, password: string){
        return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/login/`, {username, password})
            .pipe(map(user => {
                console.log(user);
                // login successful if there is a jwt token in the response
                if(user.status && user.data.token){
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in 
                    // between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }
            }));
    }

    logout(){
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }
}
```

I can solve the problem by setting `"strict": false` in tsconfig.json, but I want to follow the best practices. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

**Update:**
The User model is:

```
export class User {
    id!: number;
    username!: string;
    token?: string;
}
```

Comment: Instead of set it to null..set it to empty object..         this.currentUserSubject.next({});

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar Tried it, not working.

Comment: logout(){
         this.currentUserSubject.next({});
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');       
    } Please check this sequence...

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar Not working, showing the same error.

Comment: @ArkaGhosh if you've solved this, please tell me this solution. I'm facing the same

Comment: @HVSharma I'm sorry. I don't have a solution. Please try out the answers below. If those don't work, you can post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution in case anyone else has this issue.
I tried this and it is working in my application, and I did not disable strict checking.

```
  logout() {
     // remove user from local storage to log user out
     localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');

     // get the user nulled - typescript won't care
     this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')!));
     this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is in this line:

```
this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}')
```

On constructor, You are setting value for `currentUserSubject`, but if there is no value for `currentUser` in your `localStorage`, then it will be initiated with `null` value.

**Update**

```
logout(){
    localStorage.clear();
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>({});
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Angular. What would be the condition in if?

Comment: updated. in your case no need to check if. just `clear` localstoage.

Comment: The error is in this line: this.currentUserSubject.next(null);

Comment: Getting this error now: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'. Property 'id' is missing in type '{}'.

Answer (score -1):

Just for an suggestion let try this,

```
logout(){
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>();
    }
```

new keyword is used to initialize object. So the empty object is initialed.

Comment: Getting this error now: "An argument for '_value' was not provided. new BehaviorSubject<User>(_value: User): BehaviorSubject<User>"

Answer (score -1):

```
 logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next({} as User)
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?